# Assuming normality in RKHS

Tags: normal-distribution, normality-assumption, kernel-trick, distributions

There are some authors who assume data in a Reproducing Kernel Hilbert Space is following a normal distribution. For example, in [this article](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.77.5431&rep=rep1&type=pdf), the authors use this assumption to be able to derive analytic expressions for probability distance measures in the RKHS.

I'm particularly interested in the cases where you can't make that assumption. I've been able to find some authors who question this assumption but don't provide examples when it is going to fail.

Are there practical reasons and cases where this assumption will fail? 
In the context of the cited article, would that fail harm the distance measures?